# Why is my `if` statement evaluating to `true` when my variable is not greater than a certain number?

Tags: if-statement, command

So while I was writing an `if` statement in batch, I noticed something strange: It was triggering a command despite the fact that my `if` statement should've evaluated to `false`.

I did a separate test:

```
C:\Windows\System32>set /a l=9
9
C:\Windows\System32>if l gtr 9 echo l
l

C:\Windows\System32>if l gtr 88 echo l
l
```

Despite the fact that `9 grt 88` is false, `echo l` still executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
if %l% gtr 88 ...
```

because you want the contents of variable `l`. `CMD` is being asked to compare the literal-string `l` against the literal-string `88` because `l` is an alpha-string, not a number.

Comment: Oh, i thought it would automatically assume it was a variable